# Decompile ELF on Windows

Tags: elf, decompiling, ida

I want to decompile file `ELF 64-bit LSB executable`
with IDA on Windows, Its possible? If no, How can I do it on linux?

Thanks

Comment: `objdump` and other tools from [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/index.html).

Comment: Do you mean decompile or disassemble?, because those are quite different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to execute the binary in order to perform binary decompilation, it's something that usually happens statically, thus it'd work with ELF on Windows.

You can decompile binaries with IDA using several ways:

- [Hex Rays Decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/) from the creators of IDA itself (not free)
- [Snowman](https://github.com/yegord/snowman), open-source decompiler (free)
- retdec decompiler [plugin](https://retdec.com/idaplugin/) (free, registration required)
- [decompiler](https://github.com/EiNSTeiN-/decompiler) by EiNSTeiN
- [Ghidra](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra), open source decompiler (free)